# Navigation controller for table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Am trying to create tableview app with multiple views using navigation app template to conform to Human Interface Guidelines. But I want table on initial view to only occupy the bottom half of the screen; apparently default is for table to occupy entire screen. Is this possible? Will this result in app being rejected due to not conforming to standards?
Thank you, I am new to iOS programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the RootViewController.xib. Add a UIView to the xib and then drag the existing table view into that view. Also, be sure to set the view connection of the "File's Owner" to point to your new view instead of the tableview.

You can then customize the size and location of the tableview as a subview of the main view for the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible, and not a reason for it to be rejected.

Comment: Please, how would tableview be configured?